# Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING using netbeans 7.3.1

Tags: android, json

if you are using netbeans 7.3.1 you will get json of restful webservice  like the following 
myJson

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Appetizers","image":"iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADgAAAAkCAIAAABT8G6pAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAABb5SURBVFhHPVgHUFPrtmbevTPvvnPvO8eKKJ1ASAik ..
```

Android Code

```
   Gson gson = new Gson();      
    try {                   
    Type collectionType = new TypeToken<Collection<Category>>(){}.getType();
    Collection<Category> enums = gson.fromJson(response, collectionType);
```

exception

```
 Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 39
```

I know there is similar question but I try a lot of them and I still have the problem 
!
this is my all json file
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B01ew9ECCvc8YVNiS1JmN2gwbDA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Is that the actual JSON it doesn't like?

Comment: it is not completed I used ...

Comment: Can you post the full JSON so people can try reproducing the issue?

Comment: I notice that the error solved when I remove image from my class

Comment: but I need the image what is the problem